# How to put focus on the menu toolbar?

Tags: shortcuts

In windows machine I am used to tap the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and I have normally focus on the menu toolbars, like "File", "Edit", "View" and so on. Is there any equivalent for Ubuntu? Because, right now, if I hit the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key I get the "type your command" option.

Comment: "Because, right now, if I hit the "ALT" key I get the "type your command" option." - Which is the HUD and is basically a glorified version of what you want, as it says type what you're looking for.

Comment: you are so right, completely forgot about that feature of the Ubuntu. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't use the HUD that much, so I changed its shortcut to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and now <kbd>Alt</kbd> focuses the menu bar.

1: Open "System Settings"

2: Navigate to "Keyboard" and switch to the "Shortcuts" tab.

3: Under "Launchers" in the left column will be "Key to Show the HUD"

4: Click on "Alt" in the other end of the row and press the key you want to use instead.  (In my case <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>)

[image]

This will actually set all <kbd>Alt</kbd> based shortcuts to what they would normally be, for example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> focuses the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Because Unity works differently from Windows, the equivalent in Ubuntu is press <kbd>alt</kbd> to open the dash and then start typing the menu name that you want.

It is very useful if you just remember the menu item but not the parent menu that the item belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> for about a second to make the the menu bar become visible. Then press the keyboard button with the same letter as is underlined (mnemonic) of the word in the menu bar you want to open.